# Separability of a subring and of a pre-image

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, separable-algebras

Let $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ be commutative rings.

A known result, which can be found in De Meyer and Ingraham's [book](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540053712), says that separability of $A \subseteq C$ implies separability of $B \subseteq C$.

> When separability of $A \subseteq C$ implies separability of $A \subseteq B$?
>   By 'when' I mean what additional condition guarantees that implication.

Another, somewhat similar, question: Let $A \subseteq B$, $A \subseteq C$, $B \twoheadrightarrow C$ be commutative rings.

> When separability of $A \subseteq C$ implies separability of $A \subseteq B$?

Thank you very much for any help!

**Edit:** (1) By separable I mean the definition as in the above mentioned book on page 40 (this page is available in the preview), namely: $A \subseteq B$ is separable if $B$ is a projective $B \otimes_A B$-module.
The definition of separability also appears [here](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2016/03/27/separable-algebras/).
(2) There is an answer to a special case of my first question, due to Adjamagbo's [transfer theorem](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-94-015-8555-2_5). In that special case, 'when'= $B \subseteq C$ is flat, or 'when'= $B$ is normal.

Answer (score -2):

I do not know what definition of separability you are using.  $A\subset C$ is separable means every element of $C$ is separable over $A$ in the usual definition. Thus, for any subring $A\subset B\subset C$, clearly $B$ is separable over $A$, since every element of $B$ is an element of $C$ and thus separable.

Comment: I really apologize for not being clear enough. My rings are not assumed to be fields. The definition of separability can be found in the book I mentioned above, and also in http://people.brandeis.edu/~buchsbau/miscpapers/024.pdf and in http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1960-097-03/S0002-9947-1960-0121392-6/S0002-9947-1960-0121392-6.pdf

Comment: If we deal with three fields, then the second question also has a positive answer: By assumption $B \twoheadrightarrow C$ (surjective) and trivially it is injective ($B$ is a field), so $B$ and $C$ are isomorphic, hence separability of $A \subseteq C$ clearly implies separability of $A \subseteq B$.